# Array sorting based on another array order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am new to C and am having some issues with this code.

I need to split an array into two different arrays and sort the second array in whatever order the first one is.

Any thought please?

Below is where I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int currentN;
    int i, n;
    int array[20];
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n%2 !=0)
    {
     printf("sequence would not be equ. please enter Odd \n");
     printf("Please Enter even number\n");
     scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    //add
    printf("enter the numbers\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
     scanf("%d", &array[i]);
     //  scanf("%d", &currentN);
     // seq[i]= currentN;
    }
    n++;
    //add
    int *firstHalf = malloc(n/2 * sizeof(int));
    if (!firstHalf)
    {
     /* handle error */
    }

    int *secondHalf = malloc(n/2 * sizeof(int));
    if (!secondHalf)
    {
     /* handle error */
    }

    memcpy(firstHalf, array, n/2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(secondHalf, array + n/2, n/2 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
     printf( "%d\t", firstHalf[i]);
     //printf( "%d\n", secondHalf[i]);
     //printf( "\n************************");
    }
    printf("\n*********************\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
     printf( "%d\t", secondHalf[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the "issue" you speak of?

Comment: I'm trying to sort the second array according to the first array order

Comment: @Joh Please see this post on [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)

Comment: void main(){}....you have more problems than you think.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get what you need:

1. Create a `struct` that has two members.
2. Create an array of the `struct`.
3. Fill the `struct` array such that the first half the original array are stored in the first member of the elements of `struct` array and the the second half of the original array are stored in the second member of the elements of the `struct` array.
4. Sort the `struct` array using the first member of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code after your last `memcpy` function:

```
int j, temp;
for(i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
{
 for( j = 0; j < n/2 - 1; j++ )
 {
  if( firstHalf[j] > firstHalf[j+1] )
  {
   temp = firstHalf[j];
   firstHalf[j] = firstHalf[j+1];
   firstHalf[j+1] = temp;

   temp = secondHalf[j];
   secondHalf[j] = secondHalf[j+1];
   secondHalf[j+1] = temp;
  }
 }
}
```

I have used basic **bubble sort**, but you can use any of the advanced sorting algorithms.

The trick, is that you just have to use the `firstHalf` array when doing the comparison, but when swapping, you swap elements in both the arrays.

Comment: Thank you! It's helpful!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.